# Pandas- how can I iterate through a list to fill a column based on a condition in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a dataframe with a column ['Creation Date']. I have already created a variable for each of the 24 date ranges corresponding to a month on a 2-year fiscal calendar (May 2022 through April 2023). I also have a list of said variables.

[image]

I need to create a new column ['Fiscal Month'] and have that column filled with the values from that list (fiscal_months) based on the value in the ['Creation Date'] column. So I need it to have this structure (except the actual df is 200,000+ rows):

[image]

I tried a couple of variations of this:
`mfg_df['Fiscal Month'] = np.where(mfg_df['NCMR Creation Date'].isin([fiscal_months])`

But just got a ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given

To be honest, I'm not even sure what to try. I'm a fairly new analyst just trying to clean and transform data for a predictive model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do what I think you're asking:

- put the information about fiscal month end dates and fiscal months (names) into a dataframe `dfFiscal` ordered by fiscal month end dates
- create a dataframe `df` with a column for the creation date whose values you want to map to fiscal month
- use [`merge_asof()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to do the lookups (first ensuring that `df` is sorted by creation date).

```python
out = ( pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('Creation Date'), dfFiscal, 
    left_on='Creation Date', right_index=True).sort_index() )
```

Code to create sample input:

```python
dfFiscal = pd.DataFrame(
[
['2021-04-25','Apr21'],
['2021-05-28','May21'],
['2021-07-02','Jun21'],
['2021-07-30','Jul21'],
['2021-08-27','Aug21'],
['2021-10-01','Sep21'],
['2021-10-29','Oct21'],
['2021-11-26','Nov21'],
['2021-12-31','Dec21'],
['2022-01-28','Jan22']], columns=['Fiscal Month End','Fiscal Month'])
dfFiscal['Fiscal Month End'] = pd.to_datetime(dfFiscal['Fiscal Month End'])
dfFiscal = dfFiscal.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(dfFiscal['Fiscal Month End'])).sort_index().drop(columns='Fiscal Month End')

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Creation Date':pd.to_datetime(['2021-04-26', '2021-05-27', '2021-05-28', '2021-07-02', '2021-04-26'])
})
```

Sample input:

```
dfFiscal:
                 Fiscal Month
Fiscal Month End
2021-04-25              Apr21
2021-05-28              May21
2021-07-02              Jun21
2021-07-30              Jul21
2021-08-27              Aug21
2021-10-01              Sep21
2021-10-29              Oct21
2021-11-26              Nov21
2021-12-31              Dec21
2022-01-28              Jan22

df:
  Creation Date
0    2021-04-26
1    2021-05-27
2    2021-05-28
3    2021-07-02
4    2021-04-26
```

Output:

```
  Creation Date Fiscal Month
0    2021-04-26        Apr21
1    2021-05-27        Apr21
2    2021-05-28        May21
3    2021-07-02        Jun21
4    2021-04-26        Apr21
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your solution as written functioned correctly, except that it aligned the dataframe one month ahead. I simply changed the new df to be the Start Date instead of the End Date, changed the dates by one day in accordance with that, and that did the trick. Again, I can't thank you enough!